# HTML inserted by JQuery results in different alignment from pure HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Note: Please see the following comments by Brandson, it's the correct answer.

I have a simple form which allows users to input several languages (english, french, spanish, etc) and their corresponding levels (like a recruitment website). Every language and its level is represented by the code below:

```
<div class="form-inline" style="position: relative; left: 105px; padding-top: 20px;">
        <label>Language&nbsp;<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="languages[]" class="input-medium" style="margin-left: 16px;" value="french" readonly>
        <label style="padding-left: 107px; padding-right: 15px">Level&nbsp;<span>*</span></label>
        <select>
            <option>beginner</option>
            <option>intermediate</option>
            <option>fluent</option>
            <option>bilingual</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

The JQuery code is as below :

```
 $("#language_add_btn").click(function () {
            $("#language_add_btn").before(createEmptyLanguagePart());
        });
```

If I use a jQuery method like **before** to add this snippet of code before a certain button, the result alignment is different from which if I put directly these HTML code before the button code. I used **firefox webtools** to check the source code and dom structure, but cannot figure out what is problem. Can anyone help me ? Many thanks !
PS: As you may notice, I am using **Tweeter Bootstrap** HTML&CSS framework.

Comment: Put a space at the beggining and end of your html snippet and see if that makes the alignment come out the same when you use `before`

Comment: Could you post the snippet of jQuery code that adds the HTML?

Comment: @TheManiac I've added my JQuery code, the function **createEmptyLanguagePart()** returns exactly the same HTML code.

Comment: @Brandon I don't understand clearly what do you mean. But I would like to supplement that the language names' label align correctly, while the language input field doesn't. Really strange. :(

Comment: What I mean is that the absence or presence of spaces between your elements matters.  If you have `<label>...</label><input />` it will render differently than `<label>...</label> <input />` (note the space between the elements).  When people "directly" put the HTML in your HTML file they tend to put whitespace in there (newlines etc), but when it is a string in JavaScript, people tend to leave out the whitespace and sometimes this causes a rendering difference.

Comment: @Brandon Your answer really helps. I've spent more than 1 hour for debug. Thanks you very very much although I still don't understand why this little whitespace could have a magic effect, since in an HTML file, whitespace between tags will not influence the rendering. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I mean is that the absence or presence of spaces between your elements matters. If you have `<label>...</label><input />` it will render differently than `<label>...</label> <input />` (note the space between the elements). When people "directly" put the HTML in your HTML file they tend to put whitespace in there (newlines etc), but when it is a string in JavaScript, people tend to leave out the whitespace and sometimes this causes a rendering difference.

And yes, whitespace in the HTML file influences rendering also.  Just remember, it is not the AMOUNT of whitespace.  It is the existence of whitespace:

This renders the same as:

```
<span>a</span> <span>b</span>
```

as:

```
<span>a</span>      <span>b</span>
```

and:

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
```

And this renders different:

```
<span>a</span><span>b</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Brandon is right about this case in his answer. 
I ran into a similar situation a few times when coding a menu with list elements.

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

The code above will render with spaces between the list elements when adding `display:inline-block;` to the lists css properties.

[This article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) explains the problem very good and even provides some simple, but effective, fixes.

Maybe it'll be usefull to someone in the future :)